# Floating Point Math Confusion

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to get the percentage between two numbers for the purpose of showing the difference as far as a discount. I've tried to simplify it as much as I can but I still cant get what I want.

### Here is an example.

```
var RegPrice = 8.95;
var OnSale = 6.67;
var OnSaleAT =  Math.abs(Math.max(100.00 - OnSale / RegPrice * 100.00));
alert(OnSaleAT.toFixed(2));
```

What I'm trying to get is the `alert();` to return a value of `25.50`. However, I'm getting `25.47`.

Any ideas on how I can get this right?

Comment: You don't need jQuery for basic arithmetic operations. Also, the discount of `25.47%` is correct.

Comment: what it has to do with jQuery, jQuery is not javascript

Comment: `6.67 / 8.95 = 0.74525`, `100 - 74.525 = 25.475`, fix at 2 decimal points is `25.47`. If you want to *round*, you'll need to use `Math.round()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

25.47486... is the correct answer. If you're attempting to round to the nearest tenths, you can use:

```
var result = Math.round(OnSaleAT * 10) / 10;
```

Which outputs: 25.5  and from there you can format your answer how you like.

Comment: I would also use this code. This code has to be added after `var OnSaleAT`. The alert would look like: `alert(result,toFixed(2));`.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function() {

    var RegPrice = 8.95;
    var OnSale = 6.67;
    var OnSaleAT = Math.round(Math.abs(Math.max(100.00 - 6.67 / 8.95 * 100.00)) * 10.00) / 10.00

    alert(OnSaleAT.toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to round to 25.5%, you can just alert with a toFixed param of 1 instead of 2:

```
alert(OnSaleAT.toFixed(1));
```

Other than that, Rob W is right...the math does come out to 25.47, and there's not much you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

try `OnSaleAT.toFixed(1)+'0'` :)

Answer (score 0):

> Math.ceil(1000* (1 - OnSale/RegPrice))/10

give you "25.5"

:)